# Depending on a local package in cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've written a few packages containing some extra functions for dealing with common types that reflect the way I like to use them (for instance, I prefer to treat Bson documents as maps, rather than lists of fields). I keep these packages in local source directories, not on Hackage.

I would like to introduce dependencies between these packages in their `.cabal` files, using cabal's `build-depends` system. But this leads to the following error (`bson-docmap` being a local module):

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
bson-docmap >=0.0
```

Is it possible to point cabal to a local directory as an alternate repository?

My current workaround is to keep all my modules in a single local package, but I would prefer to break them apart if possible.

Comment: Just install the `bson-docmap` package. Once it's installed, cabal doesn't care about its origin.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using Cabal sandboxes then you can add a local Cabalized directory as a source

```
cabal sandbox add-source path/to/project/dir
```

After this point it'll be available for `build-depends`.

Comment: What if I'm not?

Comment: `cabal` does not have a `sandbox` subcommand anymore

Answer (score 10):

You may be able to create a `./cabal.project` file with content like:

```
packages:
  common/
  backend/
  frontend/
```

And then run `$ cabal new-build all`.

An example of this can be seen here: https://github.com/ElvishJerricco/reflex-project-skeleton/blob/11c1feb/cabal.project

Answer (score 2):

In your `cabal.project` file add a new section:

```
source-repository-package
  type: git
  -- Normally this is a git URL, but a local path works too (but I think it must be absolute?):
  location: /path/to/your/local/bson-docmap
  -- Replace this with the commit you want to check out:
  tag: e1a47b8802d12cd221eead508c5b4d9ccd65feb4
```

[Note that `source-repository-package` is a keyword, not the name of the package you're referring to.]